# Can I mock a constant string value that is referenced in the class under test?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have class *A* in module *a.py*, which has a method *do_thing*. The method *do_thing* uses a constant definition *CONST_VAL*, defined in *a_definitions.py* as 'Some String'. *a_definitions* is imported into *a.py*.

I have a unit test that instantiates an *A*, then calls *do_thing*. I want *CONST_VAL* to contain a different string.  I've tried many different approaches to '@patch' and '@patch.object', and I always receive some version of "CONST_VAL not defined".

I appear to have a scoping issue, but I've begun to wonder whether this is not even possible, since the value of *CONST_VAL* is imported before the mocking is called.

Can I mock an externally defined string value, and if so, how?

Comment: Please give a [mre], not just a description.

Answer (score 1):

If I have `definitions.py` like this:

```
CONST_VAL = 'Some String'
```

And `module_a.py` like this:

```
import definitions

def do_thing():
    return definitions.CONST_VAL.upper()
```

Then I can write a test like this in `test_modulea.py`:

```
from unittest import mock

import module_a

def test_do_thing():
    replacement_val = 'Another String'

    with mock.patch.object(module_a.definitions, 'CONST_VAL', replacement_val):
        res = module_a.do_thing()
        assert res == replacement_val.upper()
```